# Mount XFS under Mac OS X Lion

Tags: unix, macos, mount

I'm using Linux with XFS under Parallels. How I can mount a XFS in an efficient way? I use Transmit to mount guest filesystem as a disk, however performance is very poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that works for me and is really fast - http://macfusionapp.org/

Comment: Where can I checkout list of avaliable FS and or download them?

Answer (score 0):

what's about shared folders? I use them in good Read/Write speed.

Comment: Parallels support shredded folders under Windows only.

Comment: ha! I've installed Ubuntu (PD7) and have Parallels Shared Folders worked! May be PD6 doesn't have this feature work properly